# I Don't Understand The -> Operator For std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, methods, operators, operator-overloading

I can't seem to wrap my head around it. The `->` operator for `std::shared_ptr`, only returns a pointer to the member (let's say it is a instance of a class), yet at the same time it can be used to call methods... HOW? We are not doing anything to the pointer returned by the `->` operator. How do we call methods, and access instance variables? If I have something functionally equivalent, such as

```
T* Get() {
    return &t;
}
```

in `std::shared_ptr` (and yes, I do realise there is a `get()` method), why can I not write:

```
someSharedPtr.Get()SomeMethod()
```

That is essentially what

```
someSharedPtr->SomeMethod()
```

is doing... I am confused. How can returning a pointer substitute for something like `->->`  or  `operator->()->` syntax?

Answer (score 14):

> How can returning a pointer substitute for something like `->->` or `operator->()->` syntax?

Because the standard says so.

13.5.6 [over.ref] defines an overloaded `operator->` to Do The Right Thing:

> An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object `x` of type `T` if `T::operator->()` exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3).

If it *didn't* do that, then you couldn't implement types that act like pointers and have the usual semantics for `x->m` that users expect from a pointer-like type. So the language says that's what it does, doing anything else would make overloading `operator->` far less useful.

This actually allows you to chain calls to `operator->` to arbitrary depths, if you have a pointer-like type that returns a pointer-like type that returns a pointer-like type etc. until finally something returns a real pointer.

Comment: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42f8df8246ddcd82) of chaining `operator->` in case anyone's interested.